# Cannot link Admob account to Firebase - Must accept terms and conditions

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, admob, firebase-admob

[image]

I am trying to link my app's Firebase project to Admob, but am unable to.

I scoured the Firebase and Google analytics settings and could not find any terms I could accept. Can anyone point me in the right direction?